# How to get Decrypted password from Password Hash and Salt without Password passing to decrypt c#

Tags: c#

I have list of user's password (password Salt and password Hash )  saved in DB table. The password is not saved anywhere.

```
                var hmac = new HMACSHA512();
                var newUser = new Users
                {
                    UserName = userName.ToLower(),
                    CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
                    CreatedBy = User.Identity.Name,
                    PasswordHash = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pwd)),
                    PasswordSalt = hmac.Key

                };
                _dbContext.Users.Add(newUser);
                _dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

I need to display the password for each of the user only when needed. Say when we click on particular user with show password button by passing user ID.

Comment: If you can unhash the password, then you do have the password saved somewhere. Hashing passwords is meant to be a one-way operation, and should never be unhashed (that's why it's called "hashing" and not "encrypting", which is meant to be "decrypted").

Answer (score 3):

As @Daevin said in the comment on your post, this is not possible with your current setup. Hashing is not something you can undo (if the hash is a proper cryptographic hash that is unbroken).
https://www.techopedia.com/definition/14316/hashing-cybersecurity explains it well:

> A good hash function for security purposes must be a unidirectional
> process that uses a one-way hashing algorithm. Otherwise, hackers
> could easily reverse engineer the hash to convert it back to the
> original data, defeating the purpose of the encryption in the first
> place.

So no, you can't display the user's password unless you store it unhashed somewhere.

Comment: "unless you store it unhashed somewhere." Which you should not do. No matter how secure you think your security is, it's not.